# Rails elasticsearch with multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

Thus far I have implemented a basic search with eleasticsearch. Insert a keyword and find the item according to the title/description. 
Now I'm trying to sort the results according to distance from the users current location, but don't know how.

I have two models, the `items.rb` contains the item info and the `account.rb` has the address of the user that uploaded the item.

This is what I have done thus far:

item.rb

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user

  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 } do
    mappings dynamic: 'false' do
      indexes :title, analyzer: 'english', index_options: 'offsets'
      indexes :description, analyzer: 'english'
    end
  end

  def self.search(query)
    __elasticsearch__.search(
    {
        query: {
            multi_match: {
                query: query,
                fields: ['title^10', 'description']
            }
        },
        highlight: {
            pre_tags: ['<em>'],
            post_tags: ['</em>'],
            fields: {
                title: {},
                description: {},
            }
        }
    }
)
  end
end

# Delete the previous articles index in Elasticsearch
Item.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.delete index: Item.index_name rescue nil

# Create the new index with the new mapping
Item.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.create \
  index: Item.index_name,
  body: { settings: Item.settings.to_hash, mappings:  Item.mappings.to_hash }

# Index all Item records from the DB to Elasticsearch
Item.import
```

account.rb

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class Account < ApplicationRecord

  geocoded_by :full_address
  after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj){ obj.full_address.present? }

  def full_address
    [street, city, state, zip_code, country].join(",")
  end

  def location
    [longitude.to_f, latitude.to_f]
  end

  ELASTICSEARCH_MAX_RESULTS = 25

  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Indexing

  mapping do
    indexes :location, type: 'geo_point'
    indexes :city,     type: 'string'
    indexes :state,    type: 'string'
  end

  def as_indexed_json(_options = {})
    as_json(only: %w(city state))
    .merge(location: {
        lat: lat.to_f, lon: lon.to_f
    })
  end

  def self.search(query = nil, options = {})
    options ||= {}

    # empty search not allowed, for now
    return nil if query.blank? && options.blank?

    # define search definition
    search_definition = {
        query: {
            bool: {
                must: []
            }
        }
    }

    unless options.blank?
      search_definition[:from] = 0
      search_definition[:size] = ELASTICSEARCH_MAX_RESULTS
    end

    # query
    if query.present?
      search_definition[:query][:bool][:must] << {
          multi_match: {
              query: query,
              fields: %w(city state),
              operator: 'and'
          }
      }
    end

    # geo spatial
    if options[:lat].present? && options[:lon].present?
      options[:distance] ||= 100

      search_definition[:query][:bool][:must] << {
          filtered: {
              filter: {
                  geo_distance: {
                      distance: "#{options[:distance]}mi",
                      location: {
                          lat: options[:lat].to_f,
                          lon: options[:lon].to_f
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
       }
    end

    __elasticsearch__.search(search_definition)
   end
end

# Delete the previous articles index in Elasticsearch
Account.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.delete index:  Account.index_name rescue nil

# Create the new index with the new mapping
Account.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.create \
index: Item.index_name,
  body: { settings: Account.settings.to_hash, mappings: Account.mappings.to_hash }

# Index all Item records from the DB to Elasticsearch
Account.import
```

search_controller.rb

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @items = Item.find(params[:id])
  end

  def search
    if params[:q].nil?
      @items = []
    else
      @items = Item.search params[:q]
    end
  end
end
```

search.html.erb

```
<%= form_for search_path, method: :get do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label "Search for" %>
      <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
      <%= submit_tag "Nearby", name: nil %>
    </p>
<% end %>

<ul>
  <% @items.each do |item| %>
      <li>
        <h3>
          <%= link_to item.try(:highlight).try(:title) ? item.highlight.title[0].html_safe : item.title,
                  controller: "search",
                  action: "show",
                  id: item._id%>
        </h3>
        <% if item.try(:highlight).try(:description) %>
            <% item.highlight.description.each do |snippet| %>
                <p><%= snippet.html_safe %>...</p>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </li>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: What is the connection between `Item` and `Account` how are they connected ?

Comment: `account.rb : belongs_to :user` and `item.rb : belongs_to :user` and `user.rb has_one :account, :autosave => true, has_many :items`

Answer (score 0):

You should index the lat/lng on each item using the referenced account, don't index another document for the account. Though ES can express some relations, remember it isn't a relational DB.

Comment: I"m kind of new to elasticsearch and rails, so could you please give me a pointer on how to implement this?